# Shrink windows partition and expand linux partition

Tags: partitioning, gparted

[image: partition displayer]

So i have these partitions on my drive, i would like to shrink down `sda1` to increase `sda5`. How could i do that?

If i reduce `sda1` it does not give me options to increase `sda5`

Comment: Increase sda2 first. But you can't do it from a working system Boot from a LiveUSB.

Comment: i haven't thought about it!! I'll generate a live USB and try to do it!

Comment: You'll also need to re-install grub because starting point of `/` will change.

Comment: Before trying to shrink partition should try to remove all junk and any files you do not need/want.  Window partition should be done with windows tools, not linux tools.  If using Ubuntu version 18.04 or newer do not need swap partition either.  OS partitions should be kept around with 15 to 20% free space.  Can think about getting an external hard drive to keep stuff in and free up space.  Backing up is important if changing partitions/sizes.

Comment: You need to free more space first, by either removing more stuff from Windows and reducing sda1 more, or get a larger HDD. If you've got a current UEFI computer, this disk really should be in GPT partition format (not MBR).